# Way of setting PrimaryStage or Scene properties in TornadoFX

Tags: java, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

I am new to tornadoFX and I don't know how to setup  PrimaryStage or Scene properties like Scene height or width or PrimaryStage modality.
Please help me.

UPDATE

I want to set Scene height and width, Look at this example:

```
dependencies {
compile 'no.tornado:tornadofx:1.5.2'
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.3"
}
```

```
import javafx.scene.control.Label
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import tornadofx.App
import tornadofx.FX
import tornadofx.View

class Main : App() {
   override val primaryView = MyView::class

   init {
      // this two lines have error ( Val cannot be reassigned. )
      FX.primaryStage.scene.height = 600.0
      FX.primaryStage.scene.width = 800.0
      // or this line causes this exception ( java.lang.NoSuchMethodException )
      FX.primaryStage.isResizable = false
   }

}

class MyView : View() {
   override val root = VBox()

   init {
      root.children.add(Label("My label"))
   }
}
```

Comment: Quick tip: Tag your question with 'tornadofx' and some TornadoFX team members will be immediately notified of your question :)

Comment: @EdvinSyse thank you for answer, you are right but I couldn't create 'tornadofx' tag (I couldn't find this tag and can't create new tag because of my reputation).

Comment: Ah, it seems we had a tag but it has never been used so it was probably deleted. I'll see about getting it back. Thanks :)

Comment: 'tornadofx' tag has been added.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you don't want to let the primary view dictate the initial scene size, you can override `App.start` and configure the dimensions of the primary stage, which again will dictate the dimensions of the scene:

```
override fun start(stage: Stage) {
    super.start(stage)
    stage.width = 800.0
    stage.height = 600.0
}
```

To make this even simpler, there will be a function in TornadoFX 1.5.3 that let you create the Scene for the primary view yourself:

```
override fun createPrimaryScene(view: UIComponent) = Scene(view.root, 800.0, 600.0)
```

The end result will be the same, so you can just keep the code in the first example though.

Answer (score 10):

You should definitely check out the [TornadoFX Guide](https://www.gitbook.com/book/edvin/tornadofx-guide/details). It's a great resource for getting started in TornadoFX.

To answer your question, you can set the size in the view's root. This should do what you want (usning TornadoFX's builder pattern):

```
class Main : App(MyView::class)

class MyView : View() {
    override val root = vbox {
        prefWidth = 800.0
        prefHeight = 600.0

        label("My label")
    }
}
```

Another option is to use [type safe stylesheets](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/Part%202%20-%20Usage%20Basics/6.%20Builders%20Part%20III%20-%20CSS.html):

```
class Main : App(MyView::class, Style::class)

class MyView : View() {
    override val root = vbox {
        label("My label")
    }
}

class Style : Stylesheet() {
    init {
        root {
            prefHeight = 600.px
            prefWidth = 800.px
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage of the type safe stylesheet is you can use different units (you could set just as easily say `prefHeight = 10.cm` or `prefWidth = 5.inches`). It can basically do anything CSS can do, but is much more convenient, powerful, and (as the name suggests) type safe.

Disclaimer: I was involved in designing and building the type safe stylesheet system for TornadoFX.

Comment: Thank you @ruckus but I want to find how to setup `Scene` or `Stage` properties not it's children like `Node`s or `Parent`s, I will update my question with better example.

Comment: In that case, @edvin has exactly what you want.